# INSERT OR REPLACE WHERE ROWID Causes Error

Tags: sqlite

The following code:

```
$stm = $sql->prepare('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO "vehicle_service_invoice" (
        invoice, "date", unit, odometer, sublet, sub, po, categories
    ) VALUES (
        :invoice, :date, :unit, :odometer, :sublet, :sub, :po, :categories
    ) WHERE rowid = :rowid;'
);
$stm->bindParam(':invoice', $_POST['invoice']);
$stm->bindParam(':date', $_POST['date']);
$stm->bindParam(':unit', $_POST['unit']);
$stm->bindParam(':odometer', $_POST['odometer']);
$stm->bindParam(':sublet', $_POST['sublet']);
$stm->bindParam(':sub', $_POST['sub']);
$stm->bindParam(':po', $_POST['po']);
$stm->bindParam(':categories', $categories);
$stm->bindParam(':rowid', $_POST['rowid']);
$stm->execute();
```

Produces the following query:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO "vehicle_service_invoice" (
    invoice,
    "date",
    unit,
    odometer,
    sublet,
    sub,
    po,
    categories
) VALUES (
    7230,
    '2013-02-07',
    558,
    34863,
    0,
    0,
    1486347,
    5
) WHERE rowid = 1
```

That produces the following error:

**`ERROR: near "WHERE": syntax error.`**

---

What I am trying to do is make a single path for both my `INSERT` and `UPDATE` logic to follow, so after I found out that I could do `INSERT OR REPLACE`, I figured I could just update the information based on the `ROWID` of each item. To me the syntax looks correct, what am I doing wrong?

It should be noted that I don't care about changing `ROWID` values as I understand that is a tripping point on doing `INSERT OR REPLACE` statements. Everything is joined together in other queries based off of the `INVOICE` column. I only want to use the ROWID to refer to that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an INSERT statement, a WHERE clause does not make sense.

The INSERT OR REPLACE works as follows: a record with the specified values is inserted into the table.
If this would result in a UNIQUE constraint violation, the *old* record is deleted.

To replace a record that might already exist, the colum(s) that identify that record must be part of the values to be inserted.
In other words, you must insert the `rowid` value:

```sql
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO vehicle_service_invoice(rowid, ...) VALUES (1, ...)
```